# How to fill missing values in one dataframe from another with different shapes

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to fill some missing values from one dataframe to another but couldn't able to do this. I tried different kinds of joins, also tried to use other approaches described on StackOverflow but couldn't able to do it.

Can you help me with this?

First DataFrame is related to space launches.

```
launches.shape
Out[10]: (5726, 11)

launches.head()
Out[11]: 
        tag          JD launch_date  launch_year           type variant  \
0  1967-065  2439671.38  1967-06-29         1967  Thor Burner 2     NaN   
1  1967-080  2439725.70  1967-08-23         1967  Thor Burner 2     NaN   
2  1967-096  2439774.83  1967-10-11         1967  Thor Burner 2     NaN   
3  1968-042  2439999.69  1968-05-23         1968  Thor Burner 2     NaN   
4  1968-092  2440152.69  1968-10-23         1968  Thor Burner 2     NaN   

                mission agency state_code category agency_type  
0  Secor Type II S/N 10     US         US        O       state  
1             DAPP 3419     US         US        O       state  
2             DAPP 4417     US         US        O       state  
3             DAPP 5420     US         US        O       state  
4             DAPP 6422     US         US        O       state  

launches.isnull().sum()
Out[12]: 
tag               0
JD                0
launch_date      13
launch_year       0
type              0
variant        4981
mission          21
agency         2444
state_code        0
category          0
agency_type       0
dtype: int64
```

You can see that the agency column has 2,444 missing values which I want to fill from the other dataframe.

The Second dataframe is related to agencies.

```
agencies.shape
Out[13]: (74, 19)

agencies.head()
Out[14]: 
  agency  count  ucode state_code          type class       tstart     tstop  \
0   RVSN   1528   RVSN         SU          O/LA     D         1960  1991 Dec   
1   UNKS    904  GUKOS         SU          O/LA     D  1986 Apr 24      1991   
2   NASA    469   NASA         US  O/LA/LV/PL/S     C  1958 Oct  1         -   
3   USAF    388   USAF         US        O/LA/S     D  1947 Sep 18         -   
4     AE    258     AE          F          O/LA     B  1980 Mar 26         *   

    short_name                                            name  \
0         RVSN  Rakentiye Voiska Strategicheskogo Naznacheniye   
1         UNKS    Upravleniye Nachalnika Kosmicheskikh Sredstv   
2         NASA   National Aeronautics and Space Administration   
3         USAF                         United States Air Force   
4  Arianespace                               Arianespace, Inc.   

                  location longitude latitude error parent short_english_name  \
0                  Mosvka?         -        -     -      -                  -   
1                   Moskva         -        -     -     MO                  -   
2         Washington, D.C.         -        -     -      -                  -   
3  Washington, DC-Pentagon         -        -     -      -                  -   
4       Paris-Evry, France         -        -     -      -        Arianespace   

              english_name                                       unicode_name  \
0  Strategic Rocket Forces         Ракетные войска стратегического назначения   
1                        -  Управление начальника космических средств МО СССР   
2                        -      National Aeronautics and Space Administration   
3                        -                            United States Air Force   
4                        -                                  Arianespace, Inc.   

  agency_type  
0       state  
1       state  
2       state  
3       state  
4     private  

agencies.isnull().sum()
Out[15]: 
agency                0
count                 0
ucode                 0
state_code            0
type                  0
class                 0
tstart                0
tstop                 0
short_name            0
name                  0
location              0
longitude             0
latitude              0
error                 0
parent                0
short_english_name    0
english_name          0
unicode_name          0
agency_type           0
dtype: int64
```

I want to fill the missing agency data in the first dataframe using the second dataframe.

can you tell me how can I do this?

Comment: you can preferably create a small dataframe example for better view and so people can reproduce the question. Also if there is a common key, use merge and then fillna(). Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: Not sure if this is possible since I dont see a common key in both dataframes. Only possible candidate would be `agency_type` and `state_code`. But OP has to confirm this is correct.

Comment: @bhola prasad, you can have a look at the basics of `merging` and see if this is applicable to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101